# Avoiding the default loading of fragments in a view pager

Tags: android

i am new to android. i noticed that on implementing the adapter of the view pager the getItem() will result in returning two adjacent fragments. How can i skip this default loading and load only the fragment in the current page. Please help me.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)

Answer (score 0):

You should not do that. Please note that when swiping to next page two fragments are visible at the same time so they have both be created.

Comment: What happens in that case? I would expect it gets created then and the UI feels a bit laggy.

Comment: Try out and tell us :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) for this. I've used that to keep all my three fragments alive. I Don't know what happens if you set it to 1.

Confusing, this is from the documentation. It says this value defaults to 1 but when I was working on that I got always two fragments like you do:

> You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex
>   layouts. This setting defaults to 1.